# Django Models Radio Input

Tags: python, django

I am trying to incorporate radio buttons in my form. In my **forms.py** I have the following fields for the form :

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender']
```

In my **models.py**:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='user_id')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250
    GENDER = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Other'))
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER, null=True)
```

I want `gender` to be rendered as a radio button not a CharField. But I know the models module do not support the RadioSelect and I cannot use widget either. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you say you "cannot use widgets either". Of course you can, in the form Meta class:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender']
        widgets = {'gender': forms.RadioInput}
```