# Which library is used for importing RadioInput (widgets) in forms.py in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using radio buttons for user input in forms.py and want to save the rated value in django database.I have the following fields:

```
from product.models import Rating
from django.forms import forms
from django.forms.fields import ChoiceField
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms

class RatingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ('product', 'user', 'rating')
        widgets = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioInput(),
                                   required=True)
```

**Model.py**

```
class Rating(models.Model):
CHOICES = (
    ('5-stars', '5-stars'),
    ('4-stars', '4-stars'),
    ('3-stars', '3-stars'),
    ('2-stars', '2-stars'),
    ('1-stars', '1-stars'),
)
product=models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
user=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
rating=models.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=128)
```

I didn't find any library for importing this widget. Below is the error i am facing:

AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'RadioInput'?

Please if any one can help? Or suggest any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget is called `RadioSelect`, not `RadioWidget`. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect).

Note however, you must use the widget directly in the `widgets` attribute, not as part of a field; and `widgets` is a dictionary of field names to widgets:

```
    widgets = {'rating': forms.RadioSelect}
```

Comment: @Daniel Roasman: So which one is correct? This one Or **this** https://stackoverflow.com/a/41794420/12379095